# CRM template in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I just want to know is any CRM template present in sharepoint or Project Server for free download?
Please suggest me , it is too urgent

Answer (score 2):

When you say CRM most people think Customer Relationship Management but it could mean other things - this is why it pays to be detailed and specific on your 'urgent' questions!

As you mention Project Server it makes me think you might mean Change Request Management? If so then Micoroft has one for you :-

[Application Templates for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286.aspx)

If you mean Customer Relationship Management then I don't know of any free ones but there are a number of 3rd party ones

http://www.sharepointreviews.com/product-directory/SharePoint-Products/business-solutions/sharepoint-crm_c90_m56/